# SQL Server Stored Procedure Update and Return Single Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to call a stored procedure, give it a report id (int) and have it update a report table with a confirmation number (varchar) (confirmation # generated in the stored procedure) and return the confirmation number (i will need it to return it to a web service/website).

My stored procedure code:

```
DECLARE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateConfirmation]
@ReportID int
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @Confirmation varchar(30) = replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(16),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,120),'-',''),' ',''),':','')+convert(varchar(24),@ReportID)
   PRINT @Confirmation

   UPDATE Report
   SET  Confirmation = @Confirmation
   WHERE ReportID = @ReportID;

   RETURN @Confirmation
END
```

My call to the stored procedure:

```
execute [spUpdateConfirmation] 2
```

**I confirmed in the table the value was inserted but I get this error message:**

```
2013050219072

(1 row(s) affected)
```

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spUpdateConfirmation, Line 12
>   The conversion of the varchar value '2013050219072' overflowed an int column.
>   The 'spUpdateConfirmation' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.

Question:  What did I do wrong?

I understand what overflow is, the value is too large for an int, but I used the convert to `varchar`, inserted to table column type `varchar(30)`

I also tested this statement in SQL and it works fine:

```
print replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(16),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,120),'-',''),' ',''),':','')+convert(varchar(24),2)
```

It returns: 2013050219162

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory...

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I am converting a date value to a varchar, I dont know where the conversion to an int column comes into play...  I edited my post also to show a simple PRINT of the same thing works

Comment: Its just a warning not an error.

Comment: @Kairan Aren't you trying to convert `@ReportID int`?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I think RichardTheKiwi provided the answer, the Return statement per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx says it returns an int, so it casts the varchar to a int

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[RETURN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) from a stored procedure only allows integer values. Specifically, the documentation states:

> RETURN [ integer_expression ]

If you want to return a varchar value, you can use an output parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateConfirmation]
@ReportID int, @Confirmation varchar(30) output
AS
--BEGIN
SET @Confirmation = replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(16),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,120),'-',''),' ',''),':','')+convert(varchar(24),@ReportID)
--PRINT @Confirmation
    UPDATE Report
    SET  Confirmation = @Confirmation
    WHERE ReportID = @ReportID;
    --RETURN @Confirmation
--END
GO
```

To be called like this

```
declare @reportID int; -- set @reportID
declare @confirmation varchar(30);
exec [dbo].[spUpdateConfirmation] @reportID, @confirmation output;
-- @confirmation now contains the value set from the SP call above
```

A simpler option if you are calling this from C# is to SELECT the output as a single-row, single-column result and use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`, e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateConfirmation]
@ReportID int
AS
--BEGIN
DECLARE @Confirmation varchar(30);
SET @Confirmation = replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(16),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,120),'-',''),' ',''),':','')+convert(varchar(24),@ReportID)
--PRINT @Confirmation
    SET NOCOUNT ON; -- prevent rowcount messages
    UPDATE Report
    SET  Confirmation = @Confirmation
    WHERE ReportID = @ReportID;
    --RETURN @Confirmation
    SET NOCOUNT OFF; -- re-enable for the following select
    SELECT @Confirmation;   -- this is the value you get
--END
GO
```

Comment: `I dont know where the conversion to an int column comes into play` Because RETURN expects an INT, it attempts to implicitly cast `RETURN @confirmation` to an INT. SQL Server does a lot of implicit casts all the time

Comment: Ahh, I just thought of that and saw that MS page on the Return value being an int: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx